# SC.stream returns No Properties

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I use:

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

Sometimes I get error `Uncaught Error: AudioManager: You need to pass a valid src` because API returns `No Properties`(empty object).

Is it possible to check what API returns and skip this track.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have forget to initialize the SDK.
I only get the error without SDK init.

This should work:

```
// initialize client with app credentials
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
});

SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

Comment: I did it. Some songs play, some didn't.

Comment: i only get the error without init. for the mentioned track i always get a result. pls provide more code or a fiddle. which tracksids / urls dont work?